# Loading in new Thread

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm trying to do a loading view while I call the web service...
I have tried this:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(workerThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
//here I call the thread before call web service
 }


 -(void) workerThread {
[viewLoading setHidden:NO];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadAnimacao) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}


 -(void) threadAnimacao { //call this function is ok, but the timerLoadingEvento only is called after the call webservice ends
contadorLoading = 0;
nVoltas = 0;
nEspera = 0;
timerLoading = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(timerLoadingEvento:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
}


-(void)timerLoadingEvento:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
UIImageView *img = imgLoading;

if (nEspera == 0) {
    if(contadorLoading == 0)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_01.png"]];
    else if(contadorLoading == 1)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_02.png"]];
    else if(contadorLoading == 2)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_03.png"]];
    else if(contadorLoading == 3)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_04.png"]];
    else if(contadorLoading == 4)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_05.png"]];
    else if(contadorLoading == 5)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_06.png"]];
    else if(contadorLoading == 6)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_07.png"]];
    else if(contadorLoading == 7)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_08.png"]];
    else if(contadorLoading == 8)
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_09.png"]];
}

contadorLoading++;
nVoltas++;

if(nEspera != 0)
    nEspera++;

if(nEspera>250) {
    nEspera = 0;
    contadorLoading = 0;
    nVoltas = 0;
}

if(contadorLoading == 8)
    contadorLoading = 0;

if(nVoltas == 9)
    nEspera = 1;
 }
```

Comment: Do not update UI in thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use default activity indicator while you web service call is fiinshes

Or if you are having custom images for your progress

You can try adding animationImages (array of UIImage objects) to UImageView, set animation repeat count (0 for indefinite) & animation duration for the imageview & call imageview start animating & once web service is completed call stop animating.

Check UIImageView API guide for more details.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: why you want to use your own timer when you have built in API in UIImageView for animating images in a loop.

Comment: try to call workerThread function in main thread. like in ViewDidLoad call [self workerThread]

Comment: Thx a lot! it works...the images name was wrong..the animationImages works great! Thx